# nanohttpd connection refused

Tags: android, webview, xamarin, nanohttpd

I'm building an android app with xamarin. In it I need to load files from a local storage through a webserver into a webview. So I used NanoHttpd to create a webserver to serve files to the webview. Iloaded the jars into a jar binding library. Started a web server the same way as in the samples. Unfortunately when I try to load http://localhost:8080/ in the webview I keep getting err_connection_refused. I'm loading the app in a Sony Xperia device.

I tried alternatives to NanoHttpd too. EmbedIO for exaple. I tried to used the included SimpleWebServer or make my own that will return even a simple string just to see that it's working. I tried to load 127.0.0.1 or localhost, tried different ports. Nothing works.

Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

**Edit to add some code**

This is an example implementation copied from the helloserver sample

```
 class HttpServer : NanoHTTPD
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ServerRunner.Run(Class.FromType(typeof(HttpsServer)));
        }


        public HttpServer():base(8080)
        {

        }

        public HttpServer(int port) : base(port)
        {

        }


        public NanoHTTPD.Response serve(NanoHTTPD.IHTTPSession session)
        {
            NanoHTTPD.Method method = session.Method;
            String uri = session.Uri;
            //HelloServer.LOG.info(method + " '" + uri + "' ");

            String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
            var parms = session.Parms;
            if (parms["username"] == null)
            {
                msg += "<form action='?' method='get'>\n" + "  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" + "</form>\n";
            }
            else
            {
                msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms["username"] + "!</p>";
            }

            msg += "</body></html>\n";

            return new NanoHTTPD.Response(msg);
        }
    }
```

Here's the initialization:

```
private void StartServer()
        {

                String[] args = {

                    "--dir",
                    Application.Context.FilesDir + "/Website"
                };
                SimpleWebServer.Main(args);

                //HttpsServer.main(null);
                //  server=new HttpsServer();
               // server.Start();


        }
```

Here it's the simplewebserver from the nanohttpd package, result connection refused and logcat shows

[INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)

If I try to start with Httpserver.main I get the same and additionally

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: class md535a550fd04ddaa12bd0435e04d30336e.HttpServer has no zero argument constructor
```

If I try to start with new httpserver and then server.start I get just the string "Not Found" on the webview and no logcat errors that I can see

Comment: Try that url with browsers on your device first.

Comment: Have you request certain permissions in manifest?

Comment: I have permission internet and permission network state in manifest. It doesn't work in browser either. I'm also running the server on a parallel thread.

Comment: from an emulator like genymotion it works?

Comment: 'I'm also running the server on a parallel thread.'. A parallel thread? Why? Make it a different app to begin with. NanoHttpd is very ok.

Comment: I tried running on an emulator, same result. Tried running on the UI thread, same result. You can see why I'm close to despairing here. I edited the question to add my code.

Comment: I solved the same issue by calling `start()` after `super(8080)` in my derived class constructor